# Android Asynchronous Http Client (Loopj) POST request with headers and body

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I am working on an android application, I am using "Android Asynchronous Http Client" (Loopj) library in order to handle all the requests to the server.

I need to send a POST request with headers and JSON body.

By looking to the available POST methods in the AsynchHttpClient.java I found those:

```
public void post(Context context, String url, Header[] headers, RequestParams params, String contentType, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)

public void post(Context context, String url, Header[] headers, HttpEntity entity, String contentType, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
```

Which one should I use? What is the difference between `Header[]`, `RequestParams` and `HttpEntity`?
Which one is considered to hold the headers and which the body of the request?

Thanks for any clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between both methods are:

---

RequestParams: Additional POST parameters to be sent, in key=value format

HttpEntity: A raw entity to send, use this to send string/json/xml payloads.

---

If you want to post JSON, use HttpEntity, like ByteArrayEntity

Headers[], is an array to send the configuration headers of the request to your server. (Content-type, content-size, etc)

Comment: How to add headers in post request while using loopj ?